# ¿Cómo unir dos archivos en formato chromR?

Tags: r

Estoy intentando unir dos archivos en R con formato chromR que vienen de aquí:

```
PV003_RFO <- read.vcfR("reads_PV003_OD_filter.vcf",verbose = FALSE );PV003_RFO <- create.chromR(PV003_RFO)

PV061_RFO <- read.vcfR("reads_PV061_OD_filter.vcf",verbose = FALSE );PV061_RFO <- create.chromR(PV061_RFO)
```

Pero cuando uso:

```
        total<-rbind(PV003_RFO,PV061_RFO)
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

```
     Error in rbind2(argl[[i]], r) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Cuando busco de que clase son ambos archivos obtengo el siguiente output:

```
         class(PV003_RFO)
         [1] "chromR"
         attr(,"package")
         [1] "vcfR"
```

No se como unir ambos archivos. 
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Probaste con `rbind2()`? Se supone que mejora el soporte para métodos S4

Comment: Desde un `vcfR` puedes generar una lista con los principales `data.frames` mediante `vcfR2tidy`, y eventualmente tratar cada uno, pero el tema, que desconozco, es como luego construir un nuevo objeto `vcfR` con la la suma de los datos.

Comment: volví a repetir la acción de rbind2 con otros archivos vcf y si se unieron, por lo que rbind2 funciona para unir archivos vcf. Muchas gracias a los dos